# Multiple choosing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a selection.

1. If I press List1 it shows all  with class Link1, others hide.
2. Then I press List2 it shows all  with class Link2, and show hidden links on 1st step.
3. I press List3 it shows all  with class Link3, and show hidden links on 1st and 2nd steps.
   +I tried to use $.toggle() to make a 'undo' click, but it works not how I expect.

Here is my example:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="tg">
<tr>
    <td class="structure-left-side structure-left-side-idea">
        <h4>List1</h4>
    </td>
    <td class="structure-serviceinnova-links" rowspan="3">
        <p><a class="Link2" href="">Link2</a></p>
        <p><a class="Link1 Link2 Link3" href="">Link1 Link2 Link3</a></p>
        <p><a class="Link1" href="">Link1</a></p>
        <p><a class="Link1 Link3" href="">Link1 Link3</a></p>
        <p><a class="Link1 Link2" href="">Link1 Link2</a></p>
        <p><a class="Link3 Link2" href="">Link3 Link2</a></p>
        <p><a class="Link3" href="">Link3</a></p>
    </td>
    <td class="structure-project-links" rowspan="3">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="structure-left-side structure-left-side-patent">
        <h4>List2</h4>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="structure-left-side structure-left-side-startup">
        <h4>List3</h4>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.structure-left-side-idea>h4').on('click', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hidden-link');
    var self = this;
    $('.structure-serviceinnova-links > p > a , .structure-project-links > p > a').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('Link1')) {
            $(this).addClass('hidden-link');
            if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
                $(this).removeClass('hidden-link');
            }
        }
    });
});
$('.structure-left-side-patent>h4').on('click', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hidden-link');
    var self = this;
    $('.structure-serviceinnova-links > p > a , .structure-project-links > p > a').each(function () {
        console.log(this);
        if (!$(this).hasClass('Link2')) {
            $(this).addClass('hidden-link');
            if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
                $(this).removeClass('hidden-link');
            }
        }
    });
});
$('.structure-left-side-startup>h4').on('click', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hidden-link');
    var self = this;
    $('.structure-serviceinnova-links > p > a , .structure-project-links > p > a').each(function () {
        console.log(this);
        if (!$(this).hasClass('Link3')) {
            $(this).addClass('hidden-link');
            if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
                $(this).removeClass('hidden-link');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mw008znx/11/

I'm really wish someone can help me and explain or give some ideas.

Comment: The behavior you expect is not clear. What you have described is the correct or incorrect behavior? Then what is the opposite that is happening or expected?

Comment: FYI: you're missing an opening `tr` so your html is not balanced

Comment: @Jasen I describe the correct behavior. Now it works not so how I'd expect.

Comment: @Akiam Some of these elements have dual classes and one of them has 3 classes. When you want one class to appear while the other two classes disappear, what do you expect the dual classed (and that triple class) elements to do? What I see is when you click the "headers" the corresponding elements disappear and the only way to bring them back is by clicking the triple class element.

Comment: @ze00ne the idea like:
1. All Links visible
2. Press List1 now its chosen(active) - tags with class Link1 visible only
3. Press List2 now its chosen(active) - tags with class Link1 and Link2 visible
4. Press List3 now its chosen(active) - tags with class Link1 and Link2 and Link3 visible
5. So at this point i have all Links visible like in 1.
6. Press List3 now its unactive - tags with class Link1 and Link2 visible
7. ....

Also I'm expecting some advice - could be it done simplier? Or just left it like answer below

Comment: Hi @Akiam those combos made my head spin. 0_o Take a look at my answer so far, and tell me if I'm on the right track.

Comment: @zer00ne you are on the right way
ok what if at first all Links are hidden - so if you click all 3 Lists you see all links visible, if you click only List1 and List2 you`ll see only Links with classes Link1 and Link2 ?

Comment: @Akiam off the top of my head, I'd say try assigning `.hidden-link` class to each element within the HTML should suffice. (e.g. `<a class="Link3 Link2 hidden-link" href="">`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got the behavior right take a look: [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/nx9vmrxu/)

**RELEVANT CODE**

```
$('.structure-serviceinnova-links > p > a , .structure-project-links > p > a').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('Link1')) {
            $(this).addClass('hidden-link');
            if ($('.Link1:hidden')) {
                $('.Link1').removeClass('hidden-link');
            }
```